# MIT Scratch: Import an image with transparent background?

Tags: mit-scratch

I'm attempting to import a sprite into MIT Scratch with a transparent background. The following resource indicates "*Scratch importing for images does not support alpha transparency.*" 
[MIT Scratch Documentation](http://wiki.scratch.mit.edu/wiki/Exporting_and_Importing)
Does this mean that importing a transparent background doesn't work?? Or am I just doing something wrong during the import?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the Scratch IDE, and not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this problem in Scratch 1.4 by using a different photo editing program. Paint.Net did the job fine.

While Scratch 1.4 may not support alpha transparency (shades of transparent/color layers), it **does** support basic transparent background (100% transparent).

Answer (score 3):

Ah, that wiki article needs updating.

Scratch 2.0 definitely supports transparent PNGs, but Scratch 1.4 doesn't support alpha transparency. Which are you using?

Comment: Drat - using Scratch 1.4. I researched Scratch 2.0 and it appears to be pending release currently (ETA Summer 2013). I'm just getting started teaching my 5-year old son. Assuming best to wait for 2.0 release. Thanks for the feedback @blob8108

Comment: 2.0 is released! There's just no downloadable version yet.

Comment: That sounds contradictory to the term "release". So if it is indeed released... how does one actually attain said product without a download? Self-addressed-stamped envelope? I'm not interested in a web-only version.

Comment: You can't download it, but you can use it on the website!

Comment: Scratch 2.0 was in-browser, online-only initially, but by now you can download on offline editor too.

Answer (score 0):

I did it and I believe that you have to have image in PNG format.